# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make the bot ping @everyone?

Tags: python, discord.py

For some reason, I can't get my bot to ping everyone. I tried this-

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send("@everyone")
```

That doesn't work. I also tried `<@&role_id>`, which is what I use to ping certain roles. But that doesn't work either. I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the default role:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.message.guild.default_role)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But for some reason, the ping doesn't work in embeds. How do I fix that?

Comment: @CarterMichaelis I'm not sure how to ping a user in an embed, I too am new to discord.py, and would be interested to know how to do this.

Comment: You can't ping in embeds themselves, but you can use them outside of embeds. For example:

`await ctx.send(content=f"{ctx.message.guild.default_role}", embed=embed)`